# Change the pathname in history pathname in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I am redirecting the user using this:

```js
history.push({
  pathname: `${pathname}/order`,
  search: qs.stringify({
    id,
    group,
  }),
})
```

In current page, pathname is `/app/clients/group/active`, which I am getting from `location`.

Now, I want to redirect the user to `/data`:

```js
history.push({
  pathname: `${pathname}/data`,
  search: qs.stringify({
    id,
    group,
  }),
})
```

However, `pathname` has `/active`, which is not needed when redirecting to the `/data` route.

How can I remove it from the pathname as user is on that page.

Comment: So the url you want to navigate to is `/app/clients/group/data` from `/app/clients/group/active`?

Comment: yes this is what I am trying

Comment: Why don't you hardcode it?

Comment: Try this: pathname: `${pathname}/../data` . I haven't actually tried but it should usually work when working with directories or paths.